# Sprites names missing in plist of Texture atlas

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, plist

Cocos 2d: I have a plist of texture atlas but in plist we are not getting sprite names, only coordinates and size are there. How to use images from plist using coordinates(as name is not present)

[image]

Comment: Which tool did you use to create the plist?

Comment: I dont know the name of tool as I did reverse engineering to obtain that plist file.

Comment: Well, what's the source then? A png atlas? How are you exactly obtaining the plist?

Comment: Yes it png atlas, but in plist image names of individual images are not present.

Comment: Did my below answer worked on your side?

Answer (score 0):

My sugesstion will be re-creation of the spritesheet and the plist file. Don't loose time with a plist file without image names.

Just go to http://www.zwopple.com/zwoptex/ and use the free version of the app (or the flash version) to create both spritesheet and the plist files. It adds the name of the images into the plist. I regularly use it.